# Are RDDs in Spark multisets?

Tags: apache-spark

In [Learning Spark](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920028512.do) you can find the section "Pseudo set operations". There, it is, rightfully, stated that RDDs are not sets from a mathematical point of view. This is obviously correct; e.g. elements in an RDD are not unique. One is tempted to argue that RDDs are [multisets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset). It raises two questions:

- Are RDDs multisets or not?
- In turn:

  - If RDDs are *not* multisets, why? What is the difference between RDDs and multisets?
  - If RDDs *are* multisets, why the (multi)set-operations are not defined accordingly? For example If `M1 = [a,b,a,b]` and `M2 = [a,a,b,c]`, then from a mathematical point of view their intersection should be `[a,a,b]`. However, Spark returns `[a,b]`; kind of the purely set view of the operation. What is the motivation behind?

*N.B.: Cartesian product:* As if to add to the confusion, the cartesian product of `M1` and `M2` behaves like a multiset product; i.e. returns a multiset.

Comment: They probably considered intersection more like the set of 'shared elements', which in practical terms is often what you are looking for, most IT libraries/frameworks are rarely math centered

Comment: The confusing part is the inconsistency